# What is causing Word to start selecting text while I type?

Tags: ms-office

Periodically while typing in Word on a 2019 MacBook Pro, my keystrokes are captured by some sort of search mode that causes them to select text instead. In the example below, while I was typing "synonym", the letter "n" did not print to the screen, but caused the selection of text until the next "n" in the paragraph. Then when I typed the letter "p", the selection expanded to cover the next letter "p".

> [image: Image of selected text]

What is making me enter this mode and causing Word to select text by itself like this? Is it related to brushing the touchpad somehow?

Update: This seems to happen especially when I type the letter "y". And it also happens in Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked and answered this question [over at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1634708/what-is-causing-word-and-office-to-start-selecting-text-while-i-type/1634896#1634896). It turns out to be a Word shortcut for extending your selection, bound to F8. It only happens to me on the MacBook Pro touch bar, because of the much more sensitive function keys that I can brush when I type 'y'.

You can disable this shortcut by going to `Tools > Customize Keyboard`, selecting the category "All Commands", searching for "ExtendSelection", and clicking Remove for the F8 hotkey.